# How to detect click on mapbox-gl-geocoder results (suggestions)?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl-geocoder

When I type in and get a dropdown with suggestions (suggestions-wrapper) - is it possible to get the click event on an item in the dropdown list? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to the `result` event:

```
geocoder.on('result', result => console.log(result));
```